# How to remove forked repository from assembla

Tags: assembla, git-fork

I was playing around with assembla and I created fork of my own repository by selecting:

```
Source/Git tab -> Fork network -> Fork -> fork to a new tab in this space
```

now, I would like to delete the forked repository, without deleting the orginal one, but I can't find a suitable option. Do anyone know how can I delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have 2 tools in your space now.  You can remove your secondary tool through: Admin tab -> Tools -> delete the second tool probably named source/git.2